# How do you create a custom item in Spigot 1.16.5?

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm making a plugin that adds some useful items like House Building Wand, Exploding Sword, etc. But how can I add those items using the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you would want to make a class for your item.
For example, you can make a class `HouseBuildingWand.java` and add some Java logic in it.

```
public class HouseBuildingWand {
  public static ItemStack getHouseBuildingWand() {
    ItemStack houseBuildingWand = new ItemStack(Material.YOUR_ITEM);
    return houseBuildingWand;
  }
}
```

To make the ability, you have to use Java knowledge.
To add enchantments, flags, lore, names, check out https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Plugin_Tutorial#Item_Manipulation.
To get the item, you would need a command or an event that would give you the item.

To check how the item was clicked, you can use an event listener with the event `PlayerInteractEvent`. Example:

```
    @EventHandler
    public void onRightClick (PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player p = event.getPlayer();
        if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) {
            if (event.getItem().getType() == Material.YOUR_ITEM) {
                // insert logic
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok cool! How can I implement the events? Like I need the event: When Player Right Clicks The Item. Maybe I should override a method?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I edited my answer.

Comment: also how can i edit the NBT data of the items in the item stack?

Comment: also (again) where should I put the event handler method?

Comment: `@EventHandler` is an annotation (which goes above your listener method), not a method. Put the `onRightClick` event in a new class that implements `Listener`. And make sure to include the following line in your main plugin class: `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new YourEventClass(), this);`

Comment: What do you mean NBT data? Are you talking about name, lore, enchants, and such OR nbt tags?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228961/discussion-between-vprototype-and-yeppii).